# Sharepoint (graph) API accessing OneDrive file list - 403 / 404 error

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive

Using Postman on windows with a different user account to the onedrive user that I am trying to access, we have a list of a users personal files 'My files' shown in Sharepoint for the users OneDrive at URL:

```
https://xxxxxxxxxuk-my.sharepoint.com/personal/rob_xxxxxxxxxlimited_com/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx
```

I have registered an Add-In here

```
https://xxxxxxxxxuk-my.sharepoint.com/personal/rob_xxxxxxxxxlimited_com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx
```

I generated a clientid, secret, App Domain = localhost, redirect url = https://localhost

I have granted permissions with appinv.aspx same place, clicked 'Trust It':

I have obtained the TenantId and resource by going to client.svc. I can get an access_token with all this information no trouble:

```
grant_type  client_credentials

client_id   xxxxxxx-dbce-4a7e-bfd4-b7954546d4f8@xxxxxxx-f51f-4360-8e47-8ac7c82aecf7

 client_secret  xxxxxxx9SDjt6ELYGS4PP5NFLWxCnAWDSvxiH78fzDE=

resource    00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/xxxxxxxxuk-my.sharepoint.com@xxxxxxx-f51f-4360-8e47-8ac7c82aecf7
```

The access token returned appears to work - initially we were getting token type is not allowed but we run this in powershell and that god rid of that error:
set-spotenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false

What I want to do is get a list of files and folders at this location, and ultimately drill down to a 'Recordings' folder and download items. I'm unsure of the syntax.

```
https://xxxxxxxxxuk-my.sharepoint.com/personal/rob_xxxxxxxxxlimited_com/_layouts/15/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My files')/items
```

This returns a 404. I'm using the Authorization: Bearer eyJ...  as obtained in previous steps and Accept application/json;odata=verbose headers.

same 404 for

```
https://xxxxxxxxxuk-my.sharepoint.com/personal/rob_xxxxxxxxxlimited_com/_layouts/15/_api/web?$select=Title
```

Can anyone help with why I'm getting this? Is there a more basic API request that is more a 'hello world' to this folder?

These URLs are different I get a 403 you do not have permission:

```
https://xxxxxxxxxuk-my.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My files')/items?$select=Title
https://xxxxxxxxxuk-my.sharepoint.com/_api/web?$select=Title
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to grant APP permission to the registered app as you're using credential flow:

1. Register app

[image]

1. Grant permissions(_layouts/15/appinv.aspx)

   ```
   <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
       <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
   </AppPermissionRequests>
   ```
2. Acquire token

[image]

1. Send Api request:

[image]

More referenes:

- [Permission request scopes for list content and library content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint#permission-request-scopes-for-list-content-and-library-content)

BR

Comment: Thank you. There is a lot of detail here that looks like we are attempting this right but I will check carefully against yours. To have a final 'hello world' url as [sharepoint]/_api/web/lists is great to pin down. I'm currently doing some investigation from powerscript to see if it is user account related.